How to Use the Scan Operator in Materialized Views for Asynchronous Process Cycle Detection in ADX?
I have several independent systems that work together to perform tasks according to predefined processes.
In ADX I have a table with status messages from these systems. The status messages are not synchronized and are subject to a certain jitter. (see table and figure below). Now I want to reconstruct the process cycles.
One process states, for example, that system 1 must change from offline to online, then system 2 from offline to online, then system 2 from online to offline again, and finally system 1 from online to offline, then one cycle of this process is completed, see also the figure below.
I was able to detect these processes with the scan operator and identify them in my time series, see code snippet below.
In order to be able to perform the complex calculation asynchronously, I wanted to execute the query in a materialized view, but these do not support serialized data.
Is there a way, e.g. with a row order policy, to still use the scan operator in materialized views?
I would also be very grateful for suggestions on alternative solutions.



timestamp
system
status




YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
S1
offline


YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
S2
offline


YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
S2
offline


YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
S1
offline


YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
S1
online



scan with_match_id=match_id declare (phase: int, session_start: datetime , session_end: datetime) with
(
    step s1:
        system == "S1" and status == "offline"
        => phase = 1;
    step s2:
        system == "S2" and status == "offline"
        => phase = 2;
    step s3:
        system == "S1" and status == "online"
        => phase = 3;
    step s4:
        system == "S2" and status == "online"
        => phase = 4, session_start = iff(isnull(s4.session_start), timestamp, s4.session_start);
    step s5:
        system == "S1" and status == "offline"
        => phase = 5;
    step s6:
        system == "S2" and status == "offline"
        => phase = 6, session_end = iff(isnull(s6.session_end), timestamp, s6.session_end);
)
| project timestamp, match_id, session_start, session_end, phase
| where phase in (4, 6) 
| summarize take_any(session_start), take_any(session_end) by match_id



No, scan operator is not supported in materialized views, since serialization is not supported for materialized views, and this is required by scan. Have you considered running the query during query time, instead of using a materialized view to materialize it in the background? Is the query not performing well enough, and therefore you considered a materialized view? The best option would be to optimize the query and run everything during query time. If that's not an option, then you can orchestrate an offline process which periodically runs the query and appends the results into another table using ingest from query commands (.set-or-append)
